# Calculate a string of formula which uses pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe whose column is are `a,b,c` and index are dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["a","b","c"],index=range(5),data=np.random.rand(5,3))
```

And, I have a string called `formula = (2*a+b)/c`, where a,b,c here refer to columns of pandas data frame. What is the most efficient way to go about this?

The solution should give the same answer as this

```
(2*df["a"]+df["b"])/df["c"]
```

The bonus question is what if the formula contains lagged value `formula = (2*a[-1]+b)/c`, where a[-1] would use the data from previous row of column `a`. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your dataframe?

Comment: in addition to what @Ch3steR said, add an expected output as well. Pls, do not post pics. Just data

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas-dataframe-eval) to evaluate a string describing operations on DataFrame columns.

```py
formula = "(2*a+b)/c"

df.eval(formula)
0    6.432992
1    1.175234
2    3.274955
3    2.050857
4    7.605282
dtype: float64
```

Comment: About bonus question, no. But you should make it another question for that.

Comment: Anyway @nyan314sn can you give expected out put for bonus question? `df.eval('(2*a.shift(1) + b) / c')` this should work

Comment: actually, I think you are right.. all I need to do is formula.replace("[-1]",".shift(1)") ... That should just work.. Of course, I would need to write a function to parse numerical value of 1 for general cases.